# Error: Route.get() , can't seem to get past

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Keep getting this error, whilst trying to run my app. Low level of knowledge have tried many solutions online to fix this, but nothing has got me up and running. Here is the Error-

```
    Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (d:\dev_portal\bit_racer_real\alpha_bit_racer\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
```

index.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();


    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/catalog');
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

catalog.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

 // Require controller modules.

var horse_controller = require('../controllers/horseController');

router.get('/', horse_controller.index);


module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var catalogRouter = require('./routes/catalog'); 

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://admin:bitracer33@ds123753.mlab.com:23753/alpha_bit_racer';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/catalog', catalogRouter);





module.exports = app;
```

Not exactly sure where I have gone wrong, I have also heard that I may have a call in my routes index.js file in express. The call doesn't exist. I have spent hours going over the code making small changes, trying to get this simple error to clear :(

Has anyone else experienced this problem. Id love to get a clear answer.

Comment: `horse_controller.index` is not a function

Comment: Thanks so much. I have removed .index what you said makes a lot of sense, but I am still getting the ( Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object] ) message in console when I run it.  :(

Comment: d:\dev_portal\bit_racer_real\alpha_bit_racer\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can see, your `index.js` file is in the `horsecontroller` directory.

But when you use `CommonJS`'s `require` with a directory instead of a file, it automatically defaults that to `../path/to/directory/index.js`, so you don't have to specify `horse_controller.index` in the `app.get` function, instead just specify `horse_controller`.

The final code would look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

 // Require controller modules.

var horse_controller = require('../controllers/horseController');

router.get('/', horse_controller);


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hmmm, great tip, unfortunately it did not solve the callback issue. Is there anyfiles Im missing for this to be diagnosed?

Answer (score 1):

Like Daksh said, in the line `router.get('/', horse_controller.index);` (file catalog.js) `horse_controller.index` is not a function.

Comment: I have romoved index but I am still getting the same call back issue

Comment: d:\dev_portal\bit_racer_real\alpha_bit_racer\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

In your `catalog.js` you require your controller lke this `require('../controllers/horseController')` that means you have `horseController.js` file or `horseController` is a directory and in which you have an `index.js` file. After requiring it you save it in `horse_controller` variable and when you register It as an request handler you specify `horse_controller.index`

This presume you have exporting in your `horseController` an object like this

```
module.export = {
    index: function(request, response) {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

but if it isn't the case that why your are getting that error

> Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

This code means you have heighter you are exporting nothing in your `../controllers/horseController` file or `../controllers/horseController/index.js`

If the `index.js` file under the `horseController` directory you can pass the `horse_controller` variable directly as an request handler to the `app.get` like this

```
app.get('/', horse_controller);
```

Passing it directly because in the `index.js` file you are exporting the **Express Router** directly

Comment: var Author = require('../models/horse');

exports.horse_list = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Horse list');
};

 I just have a series of exports in my horseController.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved.

I was missing .index function from controller .js file.

added this line

`exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Site Home Page');
};`

now .index is no longer looking for an object.

Thanks for the help, appreciate the responses.  :)